# Is it true that the $\mathbb{F}_p$-rank of a linear combination of matrices is usually not smaller than its $\mathbb{Q}$-rank?

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, analytic-number-theory, additive-combinatorics

Consider fixed $3 \times 3$ integer matrices $A_1,A_2,A_3$ and the $\sim H^3$ linear combination matrices $A(\mathbf{h})=h_1A_1+h_2A_2+h_3A_3$ where $h_1,h_2,h_3$ are integers with $\vert h_i\vert \le H$.

For generic matrices $A_1,A_2,A_3$, only $\mathcal{O}(H^2)$ of these matrices have rank $\le 2$, only $\mathcal{O}(H)$ of these matrices have rank $\le 1$ and only $\mathcal{O}(1)$ of these matrices have rank $0$.

Now I am interested in the $\mathbb{F}_p$-rank of such matrices where $p$ ranges in some dyadic interval $[R,2R]$ for some parameter $H<R$ (which we may think of as a fixed power of $H$, e.g. $R=H^{1.1}$).

Here it is again easy to see that for generic matrices $A_1,A_2,A_3$, only $\mathcal{O}(H^2R^{1+\varepsilon})$ pairs $(\mathbf{h},p)$ give $\mathbb{F}_p$-rank $\le 2$ and only $\mathcal{O}(R^{1+\varepsilon})$ pairs give $\mathbb{F}_p$-rank $0$.

What I am not able to show is the following intermediate case:

**Question:** Is it true that (again for generic choices of the $A_i$) only $\mathcal{O}(HR^{1+\varepsilon})$ of the pairs $(\mathbf{h},p)$ give $\mathbb{F}_p$-rank $\le 1$?

One can interpret these results as saying that the $\mathbb{F}_p$-rank is not too often smaller than the $\mathbb{Q}$-rank of these matrices.

This is trivial if $H$ is quite small compared to $R$ since then $p$ can never divide the appropriate determinant unless it is already zero (cf. [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414820) related question). But as soon as $H$ becomes large compared to $R$, it can sometimes happens that the $\mathbb{F}_p$-rank drops, though conjecturally this should not happen too often.